# Appending a new file upload button when the previous changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that uses jQuery to add in an additional file upload button when a user adds a file. My problem is that I cannot seem to have it either add in proper format or add every time. My current function simply tries added the string directly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("input:file").change(function(){
            $("input:file").after("</td></tr><tr><td class=\"field_name span4\"><strong></strong></td><td class=\"field_option\"><input type=\"file\" name=\"pictures\">");
        });
    });
});
```

You can see a live version of this here: http://1ro.co/salem/?module=insert

The issue with the method shown above is it does not add the first two closing tags: `</td></tr>`.

I've tried methods such as setting $("input:file"); to a variable, however that doesn't set for every value after the first. For example:

```
var count = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var input = $("input:file");
        input.change(function(){
            input.after(input.get(count++));
        });
    });
});
```

However this doesn't append at all (in theory would probably append every element), and I cannot use .after() on input.get(count).

In simple terms, I'm looking to improve this and make it so it will append the a new file upload button, and not being formatted improperly. If possible, I would rather use method 2 but at the moment I would like for it to just work.

Comment: you can't append a closing tag without also appending an opening tag. When dealing with a closed document(which you are in this case), you are no longer working with opening and closing tags, instead you're dealing with element nodes that have parents and children.

Comment: @KevinB that much I figured, however at the current moment it's at least producing something. The second (preferred) method isn't making any effect at all.

Comment: I'd suggest cloning the current tr and appending it after the current tr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to re-add the handler to each new file input, so best to isolate that in a function:

```
var addfile = function() {
  var newRow = $("<tr><td class=\"field_name span4\"><strong></strong></td>" +
      "<td class=\"field_option\"><input type=\"file\" name=\"pictures\">").
    insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));

  newRow.find('input:file').change(addfile);
};

$("input:file").change( addfile );
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out your live demo and it is inserting something. But it only happens once of course as your event handler is bound only to the first object.

I would try your change function using something like the following:

```
$('input:file').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').after($(this).closest('tr').clone());
});
```

but your change handler will have to be rebuilt as well.